# Nodejs - Build using different package versions

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

I'm using private npm packages and I want to have staging, qa and production versions of those packages.
It is not a good solution to have a different `package.json` file for each application branch.
How can I have a package for each environment and make `npm install` to use that "environment version" of those packages?

ps: I'm using lerna

Comment: How would you define the different versions?

Comment: @George I don't have that process yet so I can use anything that works

Comment: You will need some way to define the versions for each environment, and that way is to have multiple package.json files with different versions of dependencies, until you define an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This just sounds like bad practice. Having different versions of a package for each environment means that dev, staging, and production no longer match and invalidates testing.

Why are you trying to do this at all?

What is the difference in functionality?

Comment: I think the question is not about good or bad practice but the possibility instetad.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this, but it's probably possible by writing a script to edit package.json based on the environment, and then running `npm install && npm start` or something.

But again, that doesn't mean you should. Ever.